# How to add a data extensions field inside an SMS message content?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am new to marketing cloud. Can anybody help me out with the mobile studio. I am having an synchronized data extension with a list of subscribers.I am going to send SMS to the list of subscribers using journey builder.Will i be able to add one of the field in data extension in the SMS content which I am sending ??

Comment: The field which I want to add is an custom field.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty clear what are you asking. Anyways, it is possible to use Journey Builder's entry source to personalize your SMS content.

> **Personalization Considerations**
>
> In Journey Builder, you can use Journey
> Builder entry source attributes to personalize your SMS messages.
> Journey Builder first attempts to pull the attribute value from the
> Journey Builder entry source. If no value is found, Journey Builder
> attempts to pull the attribute value from the contact record in the
> MobileConnect demographics table.

Important note:

> For Journey Builder SMS messages created before the October 2018
> release, attributes are still pulled from the contact record in the
> MobileConnect demographics table.

**Reference:**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_use_mobileconnect_with_journey_builder.htm&type=5